# Get current UTC timestamp in JMeter request body

Tags: jmeter, timestamp, utc

I have a API Test Plan that runs on JMeter with timestamp Parameter inside body that requires current timestamp in **UTC YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS** format.
e.g. timestamp: "2021-07-15T12:00:51.308Z"

Can someone help me with this on what & where function to be written and call so I don't have to manually change timestamp every time before I run my Test Plan

[image: Test Plan View]

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to get the current timestamp in your local time zone - go for [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time):

   ```
   ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z',)}
   ```
2. If you're in the different time zone and would like to get the current timestamp in UTC - go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"\, TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: First one add value in current timezone, wherein i want same format and value but in UTC timezone. Second one gives internal server error while running script

Answer (score 0):

Use [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) with required format:

```
${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z')}
```

Output: `2021-07-15T03:44:27.791Z`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use JavaScript:

```
${__javaScript((new Date()).toISOString())}
```

At 9:20 AM EDT, this gave me a UTC timestamp: `"2023-07-14T13:20:54.333Z"`